# Disable a button after is has been clicked, android

Tags: android, button

I am trying to disable the button after it is clicked. Th app doesn't crash it just doesn't disable it. wondering could anyone help me out?
here is the on click method for the button i am trying to disable.

```
 //Submit button for answer
        final Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
         submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText answerA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerA);

            String toCompare = answerA.getText().toString();
            TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score_text_a);
            scoreKeeper scoremgr = new scoreKeeper();

            //anaswer to input
            if(toCompare.matches("Alligator") || toCompare.matches("alligator") ||
            (toCompare.matches("Alligator ") || toCompare.matches("alligator "))) {

                //adds to score if inout matches one of the above
                scoremgr.addToScore();
                score.setText("Your score is " +Integer.toString(scoremgr.checkScore()));

                //calls the next letter class
                Intent intent_b = new Intent(button_a.this, button_b.class);
                startActivity(intent_b);

                //displays a toast message if correct
                Toast.makeText(button_a.this, "Well Done, You Got it Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                submit.setEnabled(false);

            }else{
                //displays a toast meaasge if wrong
                Toast.makeText(button_a.this, "Wrong Answer, Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked that your Toast gets called (`Toast.makeText(button_a.this, "Well Done, You Got it Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`)or verified in any other way that it is entering the `if` block? That's the only way it will get disabled

Comment: yes the input equals "alligator" the score is updated and the toast message appears then it moves onto the next class. But when i go back into this class i can still click the button and the score will update, even though i have already answered the question.

Comment: How are you coming back to this Activity? Also, if you override onResume() post that code

Comment: in button_b.class i have a back button that brings me back to the main menu and then i can go back into this class by a button on the main menu

Comment: The reason I asked is because I was trying to find out if `onCreate()` was being called or if you are setting the button in `onResume()` and that is reenabling it

Comment: no i am setting the button in onCreate()

Comment: Can you show the code which executes when you go back to `button_a` from `button_b`?

Answer (score 0):

In first place, check if your code are being executed, you are doing it right, also you can try to use to disable your button:

```
 btn.setEnabled(false);
 btn.setClickable(false);
```

Also, change your `Button` variable to an instance variable without `final`
and access it inside your `onClick` method.

If you want to remove the button from your layout, you can change the visibility on it:

```
btn.setVisibility(View.GONE):
```

Answer (score 0):

You put your "setEnabled" under an if statement. Just put it before. If that's a feature, check if the correct statement is executed, the condition is probably invalid, resulting the button not being disabled.

Answer (score 0):

in your xml file set

> android:clickable="true"

and now

> btn.setEnabled(false);
>
> btn.setClickable(false);

and check your (if condition ) does it returns true or not

Comment: scoreKeeper scoremgr = new scoreKeeper();
can anyone give me a description for this line of code? whats is doing?

Comment: @eee it creates object of your scoreKeeper class , i think you have copied code from another place .